# Display Search Block in template

Tags: theming

**DRUPAL 8 VERSION**

Hi i am trying to display the search block in a custom view named as `menu--main.html.twig`. Below is the code in my theme function

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('bootstrap_search'); 
  $variables['block_search_form'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
}
```

I am able to display the search block in `page.html.twig`. But i want to display the block in `menu--main.html.twig` Can someone guide me how can i achieve this?

Comment: You're using the wrong preprocess hook.

Comment: Can you tell me which hook should i be using?

Comment: Cool thx @Kevin .... The hook needed was **menu__main**

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong hook as suggested by kevin. The hook to be used there was `bootstrap_preprocess_menu__main` .... It all became cleared after reading this comment https://api.drupal.org/comment/62602#comment-62602